# While reviewing, what should be done if code or an image from another source is pasted by an editor?

Tags: discussion, support, review, suggested-edits

An editor had [copied pastebin code to a post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1068608).

Is it part of a review? Should an image or code from another website or resource be copied while editing?

While I wrote this question, the reviewers approved the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having as much of the information relevant to your question present in the actual question has several advantages:

- The number of clicks required before you can begin to answer the question goes down
- It helps ward off [link rot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot), which in itself has two benefits

  - It makes sure the question won't be crippled if the external link gets taken down, and that it continues to be useful to other people
  - It improves the search engine rating of SO questions